# What is the correct DatePicker SelectedDateChangedEvent Handler type for a FrameworkElementFactory

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2013, datagrid, datepicker, event-handling

I am creating a column of bound DatePicker controls in a DataGrid control.  For each of the DatePicker controls I would like to attach a SelectedDateChangedEvent handler, but I am having difficulty doing this.

Consider the following code for WPF:

```
private void dg_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "Event Date")
    {
        var f = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(DatePicker));

         ...

        // I tried this:
        //f.AddHandler(DatePicker.SelectedDateChangedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(aRoutedEventHandler));
        // and I tried this:
        //f.AddHandler(DatePicker.SelectedDateChangedEvent, new SelectionChangedEventHandler(aSelectionChangedEventHandler));

        e.Column = new DataGridTemplateColumn()
        {
            Header = e.Column.Header,
            CellTemplate = new DataTemplate() { VisualTree = f },
        };
    }
}

private void aRoutedEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)   { ... }

private void aSelectionChangedEventHandler(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {...}
```

Trying either of the event handlers result in an "Argument Exception":

> A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>   Additional information: Handler type is not valid.

What is the correct handler to use?

Comment: Do the objects in your collection support INotifyPropertyChanged? If so, you can try hooking into that instead of hooking into the underlying control events.

Comment: I deferred what I intended to do in the event handler to the time of validation.  I am still going to leave this question unanswered, although I believe that it is a bug.  (I have done what is illustrated in the code above with a ComboBox control and an error did not occur).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the handler as follows for the DatePicker SelectedDateChangedEvent

```
f.AddHandler(DatePicker.SelectedDateChangedEvent, new EventHandler<SelectionChangedEventArgs>(aSelectionChangedEventHandler));
```

The handler type can be found by looking into the DatePicker class at the public events declared

```
public event RoutedEventHandler CalendarOpened;
public event RoutedEventHandler CalendarOpened;
public event EventHandler<DatePickerDateValidationErrorEventArgs> 
public event EventHandler<SelectionChangedEventArgs> SelectedDateChanged;
```